# IK not smooth - snapping

Tags: animation, rigging, inverse-kinematics, graph-editor, dopesheet

I have rigged a low-poly block character so that it has an IK armature.  The problem is that when I try to animate it, when the legs get close to extending straight, the leg will be moving smoothly, then it will quickly snap straight.

This does not look realistic at all.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Yeah I've had a similar problem, all I know how to do is just to keep the distance from getting to that snapping point by adding a distance constraint.

Comment: that's not the best solution, though, because then the leg will never straighten.